# How to model a spoon with using edge loop only with no mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, extrude

Is it possible to use only edge loop for making the round side of a spoon? What I have done at first is making a plane shape and scaled it. After that I extruded the upper edge of the spoon. Then, I used edge loops to make the extruded part to become round which the problem is it the top of the extruded part cannot be round. Is there really no way to make a spoon just by using a plane shape? This is the image of what I have done before posting the question 
[image]
Is there anyway to make the upper side of this image to be a circle or almost circle?

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. There's a saying in business: 'There's more than one way to make a cup of tea' (also, 'There's more than one way to skin a cat'). Try including an image of your work, or better, upload your blender file. Making any object can be done in several different ways: it's down to the personal preferences and skills of the designer. But I anticipate that a subsurface modifier and proportional editing ('O' key toggle) may be in your near future.

Comment: I have attached the image. Is there any way to make the upper part look more like a circle?

Comment: Lemon nails a good workflow for spoon creation, and I'd suggest it's the most efficient one, as the use of modifiers minimizes geometry while maximizing flexibility on design. To answer your follow-up question: it looks like you currently have a rectangular shape for your spoon's neck. The most circular shape you can get is a square. To get it more circular you need more geometry. CTRL-R, hover over a horizontal edge, and scroll to generate two loop cuts. That should give you four more points to that square, giving you 8 vertices for a better circle.

Comment: @arcv, the more vertices the less subsurf modifier will influence the shape. In the attached image we don't see the upper part, but I guess it is open geometry. You need to make a face here, and probably give a loop cut vertically along the whole shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility is to use *solidify* and *subdivision surface* modifiers, starting from a plane.

- Create a plane
- Adjust its size
- Subdivide it twice
- Adjust the center part depth
- Adjust the extremities

[image]

- Now add the modifiers
- Refine the geometry as you want
- Set the shading to *smooth*

[image]