# Can not bend shape because I can not subdivide it

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to bend this plate like object, but seems it needs to be subdivided first.

I forgot to subdivide it at the beginning, now after all steps, it is complicated and can not be subdivided now (or say I don't know how to subdivide the big plate now).

How should I do to bend it like an U curved bend spoon?

[image]

Comment: maybe use the Knife Project tool as I explain here except you just need edges on the Y axis, not X: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273923/how-to-bend-a-closed-mesh-spherically/273926#273926

Comment: That is not a favourable starting point to model a spoon, Blender is not a CAD program. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107387/how-to-model-a-spoon-with-using-edge-loop-only-with-no-mirror-modifier

Comment: Thanks Duarte and moonboots.  @moonboots, your idea is great! Yes, knife project tool can subdivide anything, except the combined objects are too complicated and the cutting killed my Blender few times, but anyway it works fine.